# Palm plant wilting/drooping (pics added)

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, palm

UPDATE: Found some white dots that are extremely tiny. Not sure if they are scale or mineral deposit from water. The palm plant has also closed all of its leaves.

[image]
[image]

My palm plant was doing great and was quite stiff/upright. I re-potted it into another but better potting mix and it loved it, as it got even more upright. However, it suddenly started drooping. Now even after watering, the plant is going sad and not happy. I don't know what to do. I have moved the plant now to even more brightly-lit indirect lighting but no improvements. The soil drains very fast and the pot has a drainage hoke at the bottom.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of soil is that? I might suspect a pH or watering issue. Maybe there's not enough manganese available, possibly due to a too high pH or a deficiency. However, palms use a lot of manganese, I've read. Just a guess. I don't know.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx it is a mix of pumice, peat, loam soil, vermicompost.

Comment: FYI  --  it is a phoenix roebelenii (pygmy date palm or miniature date palm).

Answer (score 1):

That looks a bit like a scale infestation maybe?

"Infected palms show tiny white spots on the undersides of the leaves. In time, the spots merge and the fronds look like they've been "whitewashed" or painted white. Some fronds may turn brown on top and still be white on the bottom, or they may turn brown entirely and curl up or even drop from the plant."

This is a link that might be of some help?

https://www.hunker.com/12554598/white-spots-on-palm-leaves

How do the spots feel on the touch?

Comment: Those white spots were only on the edges and extremely hard to get off. I lost patience and cut it all back to just the stump. the newer stalks also had them and they got very dry and sticky. Most probably scales.

Comment: Aww, sorry to hear, it can be tough to get rid off :/

Comment: Yeah it was quite beautiful and was very happy before getting scales